# How to group dictionaries into multiple arrays in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

In my application I have few dictionary objects in one array. In each dictionary object I have one key value pair that is date = 02/05/2014.

Now my requirement is I have to show all these objects in different sections based on date. Can any one please help me how can I filter objects based on date to show in different sections in a table?

Note: Each object contains different dates.

Comment: Is the value of type NSDate? or NSString ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to sort array using NSSortDesciptor using following code :

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]]];
```

This will ensure that your dictionaries are sorted based on date and its easy to group them.

You need to write logic to group them based on date. Compare dates and group them accordingly.